# oEmbed in wordpress multisite not working

Tags: multisite, block-editor, oembed

We've multisite on single wordpress installation. For example,

Main site - testsite.com/
Sub site - testsite.com/subsite

Now when I try to embed a blog from subsite into mainsite or vice verca or post of subsite into subsite, it gives the error ***Sorry, this content could not be embedded.***
Also when I see network call I see this error response,
`{"code":"oembed_invalid_url","message":"Not Found","data":{"status":404}}`

This is how I'm embedding a blog from subsite.
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you trying to "embed a blog"?

Comment: I've added the image in the question.